# How do I generate a result document based when Saxon will not work for me?

Tags: xml, validation, xslt, dtd

I have been working on this project for days. The assignment wants me to create a XSL stylesheet cased on the XML file and also based on the DTD file. Once I FINALLY got the XLT file to validate (I hope I did everything right), I tried for hours to generate a result document in XML but without luck. I downloaded Saxon, which is recommended in the textbook, but I kept getting an error message even though I extracted the files and such. Is there an easier way to generate the result xml document? I also need to make sure that validates as well.

Here is the source code:

```js
DTD file


<!ELEMENT customers (customer)*>

<!ELEMENT customer (order)>
<!ATTLIST customer id CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT order (qty, date, amount)>
<!ATTLIST order orderid CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT qty (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT date (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT amount (#PCDATA)>



​
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml"
  doctype-system="customers.dtd"
  encoding="UTF-8"
  indent="yes" />
  
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:comment>
 Author: Paulina Crawford
 Date: 10/10/2015
 </xsl:comment>
 
<xsl:element name="customers">
  <xsl:apply-templates
   select="orders/order">
      <xsl:sort select="custid" />
   </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:apply-templates select="order" />
<xsl:element name="customer">
 <xsl:attribute name="id">
   <xsl:value-of select="custid" />
 </xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:element name="order">
   <xsl:value-of select="@orderid/id" />
   <xsl:value-of select="@qty" />
   <xsl:value-of select="@date" />
   <xsl:value-of select="@amount" />
 </xsl:element>
<xsl:value-of select="custid" />
</xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>​
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>


<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="clist.xsl" ?>

<orders>
   <order id="OR3124" qty="1" custid="CUST204">
      <date>5/1/2017</date>
      <amount>$108.24</amount>
   </order>
   <order id="OR3125" qty="2" custid="CUST117">
      <date>5/1/2017</date>
      <amount>$78.21</amount>
   </order>
   <order id="OR3126" qty="1" custid="CUST311">
      <date>5/1/2017</date>
      <amount>$45.93</amount>
   </order>
   <order id="OR3127" qty="4" custid="CUST091">
      <date>5/2/2017</date>
      <amount>$68.21</amount>
   </order>
   <order id="OR3128" qty="1" custid="CUST137">
      <date>5/2/2017</date>
      <amount>$117.24</amount>
   </order>
   <order id="OR3129" qty="1" custid="CUST128">
      <date>5/3/2017</date>
      <amount>$75.68</amount>
   </order>
   <order id="OR3130" qty="2" custid="CUST083">
      <date>5/3/2017</date>
      <amount>$58.93</amount>
   </order>
   <order id="OR3131" qty="1" custid="CUST304">
      <date>5/3/2017</date>
      <amount>$112.25</amount>
   </order>
</orders>​
```

If anyone can please offer any assistance, I would be eternally grateful...

UPDATED code:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"
 doctype-system="customers.dtd"
 encoding="ISO-8859-1"
 indent="yes" />
 
 <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:element name="customers">
       <xsl:apply-templates
         select="orders/order">
          <xsl:sort select="custid" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:element>

          <xsl:apply-templates select="order">
          <xsl:element name="customer">
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="@custid" />
          </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:element name="order">
        <xsl:attribute name="orderid">
           <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
       <xsl:element name="qty">
           <xsl:value-of select="@qty" />
       <xsl:element name="date">
         <xsl:value-of select="date" />
    <xsl:element name="amount">
      <xsl:value-of select="amount" />
   </xsl:element>
         <xsl:value-of select="custid" />
   </xsl:templates>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There's no point telling us that you got an error message if you don't tell us what the error message was. Furthermore, there's no call on xsl:result-document in the stylesheet code you submitted. So we have absolutely no idea what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, we've no way of seeing how your call on xsl:result-document was wrong without seeing that code, or seeing the error message. Here are some things that are wrong in the code that you have shown us:

You refer (twice) to custid as an element name, but there is no element called custid. Perhaps you intended the attribute of that name, which would be @custid.

You refer to attributes @date and @amount, but these are elements in your source, not attributes. You also refer to @orderid/id, which cannot exist in any XML document: attribute nodes do not have elements as children.

Finally, all your code is in the "root" template (with match="/"), but most of your path expressions could only make sense if the context item were an "order" element.

Frankly, I think you are going about this assignment the wrong way. You say you've been working on it for days. I suspect that you have been spending this time trying to get code working, whereas you should have been spending the time sitting in a comfortable chair reading a book. After two days reading of any reasonable XSLT textbook, ideally doing some of the worked examples, you would have little trouble writing this stylesheet in an hour.

Comment: Thank you for the honest words. I genuinely appreciate knowing what is wrong with my code. I am actually very new at XML and XSL but I went with your suggestions. Honestly, I am having trouble understanding it despite my background in HTML. I added my current code to the OP, and I was not given an error message, which is why I assumed it was pretty much finished. The assignment also told me to sort by custid...

Comment: Compared with many modern languages, XSLT is not good at detecting errors statically. A great deal of the time, if your code is wrong, you will just get wrong output. That was actually part of the original design philosophy, shared with HTML, and considered suitable for the browser world: garbage in, something out. Static error detection has improved in later XSLT releases if you go for schema-aware XSLT, but it's still far from perfect.